# Selenium C# Webdriver IE11 issues

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am struggling through what appear to be issues with WebDriver properly interacting with the Internet Explorer Server (IE11).  I have quite a number of tests already authored and working in Chrome but when I try to run the exact same tests using the latest IE Driver server (2.46.0 - downloaded from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

I have read a number of articles on setting up a registry entries and adding my site to the list of trusted sites to to possibly handle a few of these issues but I have been un-successful ([Selenium WebDriver on IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782891/selenium-webdriver-on-ie11))

Within the page above, one of the responses links to a Microsoft site for downloading IE Web Driver for IE 11 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44069), this link wants to download and install something.

My question:  Is there a difference in the WebDriver from the Selenium site versus the MS site?

Thanks
Sean

Comment: I use the only from seleniumhq without any issue. What is the issue exactly? Does not interact with the element at all or loses focus? can you also provide the stacktrace?

Comment: The issue is in some cases the Driver is timing out when trying to locate an element.  For example   {"The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:16932/session/2a9ec4f8-f013-42a0-803d-bcf04e40ceed/element timed out after 60 seconds."}

Comment: Thanks Saifur<br/>
The issue is in some cases, (more than a few), the Driver is  timing out when trying to locate an element.  For example I have a line of code as follows  
`IWebElement addressTab = getDriver().FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(ADDRESSES_TAB));`
When its trying to ""find"" this element, the driver time-out occurs and I am left with the following  
{"The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:16932/session/2a9ec4f8-f013-42a0-803d-bcf04e40ceed/element timed out after 60 seconds."}

This same code runs correctly  in Chrome and FireFox

Comment: Can you share how you instantiation the iedriver?

Comment: [TestInitialize()]  
public void MyTestInitialize()   
{  
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(PATH_TO_IE_SERVER);  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));  
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));  
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();  
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the native event for IE shown as follows

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions { EnableNativeEvents = false };
options.AddAdditionalCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
```

Also, [DesireCapabilities](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities) expands the ability of controlling driver instance more.

Comment: Thanks Saifur, seems much better.  Will post back with more results soon but overall it seems to be working properly.   Where can i find out more info on what the available choices are for the InternetExplorer options object?

Comment: Happy to help. Added the link

Comment: Worked really well thanks so much.  So I am satisfied with the answer but I am still trying to understand what "EnableNativeEvents" actually does.  I do not see it on the page you references.  Just trying to better understand what this flag is actually doing under the covers.

Comment: JimEvans explained it well [here](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2013/01/revisiting-native-events-in-ie-driver.html). If this is answer you had been looking for don't forget to accept and thumbs up