# Selenium tests don't work in IE11

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, internet-explorer-11

I'm working with automation tests on C# + Selenium WebDriver. I stucked with the problem, tests on IE11 don't work, but work on Firefox, Chrome, IE10.

The problem is in the next part of code:

```
    try
    {
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(PAGELOAD_DELAY))).
            Until(driver1 => ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).
                ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete"));
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException ex1)
```

Error from VS2015 debugger:

[image: VS2015 debug error]

I've tried the next but it didn't help

- In IE11 protected mode turn off/on for all locations
- In registry add `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_DISABLE_INTERNAL_SECURITY_MANAGER]`,  `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE]`
- different versions of Selenium WD
- both x32 and x64 versions of IE11 WebDriver
- [Microsoft IE11 WebDriver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44069)

My test environment:

- Windows 8.1 x64
- VisualStudio 2015
- Selenium WebDriver 3.0.0 beta2
- IEDriverServer Win32 2.53.1
- NUnit 3.4.1

**UPD1**

1. Tried add web-site to "Compatibility view list"
2. Tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249459/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-ie11-issues?rq=1)
3. Tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782891/selenium-webdriver-on-ie11?rq=1)

no results, the same error

**UPD2**

I've created simple project to check IE11 driver. Code is next:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        try
        {
            (new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000))).
            Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Name("q")));
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException ex)
        { }
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("123");
    }
```

Page with google was opened, but I've got an error during debug:

```
    Result StackTrace:  
    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByName(String name)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Name>b__8(ISearchContext context)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
       at UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in C:\dev\VS2015\Projects\UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1\UnitTest1.cs:line 21
    Result Message: 
    Test method UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with name == q
```

Is there any possibility to run selenium tests under IE11, or it's driver completely broken?

Configuration from test project:

- VisualStudio 2015
- Nuget Selenium.WebDriver 2.53.1
- Nuget Selenium.Support 2.53.1
- Nuget Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver 2.53.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Check the emulation mode of your browser

Microsoft Edge ?
IE 11 ?

set it to IE 11 .

Comment: Default mode is Edge. I cannot change default mode in IE11 for all sessions. Maybe it's possible to set up from code, not sure. I've added my web-site to the "Compatibility view list", so site should be opened in IE7 mode. But I got the same error.