# IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070012 ('There are no more files.')

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a bit of a problem when using IEDriver on Windows Server 2012 R2. On Windows 10, the ChromeDriver,IEDriver and GeckoDriver are working perfectly however, on the Windows Server only ChromeDriver works.

> IEDriver is returning OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected
>   error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT
>   80070012 ('There are no more files.')

I have added these configurations:

- Same Protection Mode
- Registry Key Changes
- Added PATH

Versions:

- IE 11.0.9600.17416
- Selenium.WebDriver 3.5.1
- IEDriverServer 3.6

The code I am currently using is this (C#):

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
return ieDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver("Path To IEDriver", options);
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this error?

Comment: IMO, `IEDriverServer 3.6.0.0` is compatible with `Selenium.WebDriver 3.6.0` but not with `Selenium.WebDriver 3.5.1`. Either bump up `Selenium` to v3.6.0 or bump down `IEDriverServer` to v3.5.1.0.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for your suggestion however the issue persists, just tried 3.5.1

Comment: Which Selenium binding are you using Java/Python/C#/Ruby/NodeJS ?

Comment: @DebanjanB I am currently using C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding "options.EnsureCleanSession = true;" solved the issue for me:

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
options.EnableNativeEvents = false;
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
```

Advice from the source I used: [Selenium WebDriver on IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782891/selenium-webdriver-on-ie11) :

Local:

```
var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
//Clean the session before launching the browser
options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
```

Remote:

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
capabilities.SetCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);
```