# Selenium running on windows 10 with Dameware and IE11 finds no elements

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11

I am running selenium via Dameware on a Windows 10 machine to IE 11.  (When I run from my desktop with Windows 7 and IE 11 it works fine).  It needs to look for a username input field and input a user name:

[image]

It is not finding any elements.  To see what elements it thinks it had, I put some code:

```
        String xp = "//*[contains(text(), '_TXT_')]".replace("_TXT_", txt);
        addComment("xp is " + xp);
        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        List<String> hlist = Lists.newArrayList(handles);
        boolean found = false;
        Integer hsize = hlist.size();
        addComment("Number of list handles = " + hsize.toString());
        hsize = handles.size();
        addComment("Number of arr handles = " + hsize.toString());

        for (String handle : hlist) {
            addComment("Handle is " + handle);
            addComment("URL is " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        }
        for (String handle : hlist) {
            addComment("Handle: " + handle);
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);

            List<WebElement> eles = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
            for (WebElement ele : eles) {
                String tag = ele.getTagName();
                String id = ele.getAttribute("id");
                String nm = ele.getAttribute("Name");
                addComment(handle + ": " + "//" + tag + "[@" + id + "=" + id + " + name = " + nm);
            }
            WebElement e = SeleniumTools.waitForWebElement(By.xpath(xp), 20);
            found = (e != null);
            if (found) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            throw new KDTException("No window found");
        }
```

This should examine every window accessible by the driver and print every element it finds (because I used "//*").  When I run it, if finds 1 window, 1 handle but no elements.  (addComment adds the comment to the log file).

I pass the text in to search for.  In this case it is actually "assword" to find the window with that text.  But it never gets that far as it finds no elements.  You can see the element is there from the picture below.
[image]

so I am not sure why it is not finding anything.  All my zones in IE are set to protected.  (I also tried with protected mode off for all).
and yes we do need to use IE because Chrome can't handle some of the functionality.

Comment: I would like to know what functionality Chrome can't handle? But as to your original question, check to see if you have this registry key set on the machine running selenium (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782891/selenium-webdriver-on-ie11), its in the OP's question (post)

Comment: To answer the first question, apparently, Chrome cannot handle Cold Fusion.  To answer the second question, I have contacted our sys admin to check the registry.  I don't think I can check it myself?

Comment: Actually I was able to set that.  Do I need to relogin or anything because I am having the same problem still.

Comment: you may need to restart the machine for it to take effect, yes. Also, this may not be an actual problem with Chrome, but the files, (https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2316409)

Comment: Could this cause a ransom ware attack?

Comment: Could what cause a ransomware attack?

Comment: Setting that registry value.  I got a notice from Varonis about a ransomeware attack.

Comment: To be honest, I really don't know if it opens it up to an attack, I worked for a company that did lots of automated testing, we had hundreds of VMs with that registry key and we never had any issues. It could be that editing the registry at all may cause your software to throw a warning, but I am not familiar with Varonis, so I can not say for sure.

Comment: @Tony Where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: Hi Debanjan. IEDriverServer opens the login page but it cannot find any elements.  This is on a machine to which I am connected via Dameware and Windows 10 (IE11).  It workes from my desk which is Windows 7 and IE11

Comment: I view page source (driver.getPageSource()) and it shows the elements.  Not sure what is going on.  It may be created by java script.  Do you have to do something special to access html created by Javascript?

Comment: Actually I tried setting everything that looked like java script.  Weird thing is, I run it on the same machine in a friend's login and it works.  I tried to copy all the settings from his to mine.  Is there an easier way than taking screenshots of all the internet settings?